# How to enforce implementor to do something

Tags: c++, oop

Suppose I have the following classes:

```
class X;
class Y;

class Collection
{
   public:
      virtual void AddItemX(X*) = 0;
      virtual void AddItemY(Y*) = 0;
      //So on...
};

class Collector
{
   public:
      virtual void Fill(Collection&) = 0;
};
```

Is there any way to ensure that an implementation of `Collector` class will fill all the needed items in the passed `Collection` class?

Comment: In the documentation threaten the implementer with a class-action lawsuit. That should do the trick :)

Comment: :D. How about I put a curse on the class?

Comment: People don't believe in curses these days. Only in lawsuits :)

Comment: If you put both the curse AND the lawsuit in the license agreement, you cover all the bases.  (Of course, getting someone to read the license is another issue....)

Comment: "I hope your program reeks of memory leaks!" Is a curse like this too evil?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method, given a known number of AddItemX() calls is to move those AddItem() functions to protected and have the Collection class keep track of the additions and the number, e.g:

(I actually don't like this solution, lol, but given your design it would suffice:)

```
class X;
class Y;

class Collection
{
private:
    int m_nItems;
    int m_nItemsAdded;

protected:
    virtual void AddItemXImpl(X&) = 0;
    virtual void AddItemYImpl(Y&) = 0;

public:
    Collection() : m_nItems(2), m_nItemsAdded(0){};

    void AddItemX(X& _x) {m_nMethodsAdded++; AddItemXImpl(_x); };
    void AddItemY(Y& _y) {m_nMethodsAdded++; AddItemYImpl(_y); };

    // function to find out if we're filled
    bool isFilled() const {return(m_nItemsAdded == m_nItems); };
}; // eo class Collection
```

EDIT: For clarification, your Collector could be implemented thusly:

```
class Collector
{
protected:
    virtual void FillImpl(Collection& _collection) = 0;

public:
    void Fill(Collection& _collection)
    {
        FillImpl(_collection);
        if(!_collection.isFilled())
            throw(std::exception("Not filled dammit!"));
    };
}; // eo class Collector
```

Comment: This allows you to keep track of what's been filled, but doesn't necessarily self validate (i.e. throw an exception if everything hasn't been filled) **Something** has to call isFilled()!

Comment: I have amended my post to include an implementation of the Collector class that will throw the exception.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, write a [unit test](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CC8QFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcpptest.sourceforge.net%2F&ei=UFHRTLiEJISglAff8LXQDA&usg=AFQjCNGmuNM-qgWdNzlT7zG5q13ko2DIlQ) for Collector with a mock Collection.

Compile time enforcement? No.

Runtime enforcement? Yes, with a lot of overhead in the Collection class.

Comment: If the Collector is implemented by a 3rd party then it may be difficult to unit test (i.e. the only power you have is to tell them to write unit tests).

Comment: Publish the unit tests and tell them to conform in your documentation. Ultimately, there's only so much you can do automatically or at compile time: if they want to blow their legs off you cannot always stop them.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing something above, what is calling Collector::Fill()? It's there that you need to check that the Collection has been filled...

EDIT: Do you have control over where Collector::Fill() is called from? This is the only place where you can check to see if it the Collection has been filled correctly. One other option is you pass everything by value, and in the copy constructor (or assignment) you check..

Answer (score 1):

assert statements can be a good way to document and test that something has met your assumptions in cases like this.

Answer (score 1):

One of the things you give up when you leave a method for future developers to implement is control over how they do it.  You can add a comment making your recommendations, but it's on them to do what's appropriate for their subclass.  After all, you can never really be sure how your class will be used down the road.

Comment: True, but there are things we **can** do - which is what I am asking about in this case. Is there anything that can be done to make sure that an implementor will implement it right? I mean code-level.

Comment: It's the "implement it right" part that bothers me.  You can check in your code to make sure that the structure isn't empty before you use it, and return an error code, or throw an exception, or whatever.  I'm just trying to point you that you don't actually know what *right* is.  You know what you expect, but your class may be extended in the future in ways you don't expect, and there's no good reason to impose restrictions on future users.  If you need the collection to have something in it, and it comes to you empty, do nothing.  Other than that, leave it open.

Comment: Point taken. I am talking about a bunch of pure virtual functions anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the class definitions to encourage correct usage by checking `Collection` validity at `Collector` construction time, and disallowing default construction of `Collector` or modification of the encapsulated `Collection`.  Have the `Collector` constructor validate the Collector using a pure virtual method.

This does not guarantee correctness - `Collection` implementors can still cheat by allowing in malformed subclasses - but does support it by expressing what you want more clearly.

```
class X;
class Y;

class Collection
{
   public:
      virtual void AddItemX(X*) = 0;
      virtual void AddItemY(Y*) = 0;
      //So on...

      virtual bool ensureValid() = 0;
};

class Collector
{
   public:
      Collector (const Collection coll&) : _coll(coll)
      {
         if (!coll.ensureValid())
         {
           // throw an error
         }
      }

   private:
      Collector();

   protected:
      const Collection _coll;
};
```

Comment: The `Collector` class is the one who `Fill`s the `Collection`.

Comment: See another answer from @Nim - who is calling `Collector::Fill`?  if it's only `Collector` then this should be `protected` not `public`.